# I'm trying to connect two computers with unity NetCode but don't successes

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm trying to create a multiplayer game with Unity NetCode and I'm doing well but, when I'm connecting from anther computer I'm aren't successes.

the computers are connect to the same network but one with Wi-Fi and anther with Ethernet cable, from the same computer it does working
I think the U Net Transport have something to do with it

does any body have any idea why I'm failing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Nevermind I fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

1. first you need to check if the computers answer to ping, by default windows doesn't allow answer to ping.

   Tutorial - https://youtu.be/1BGdvSyAADw
2. In the network u net transform there is a connection ip, make sure that connectio ip is right. by default the connection ip is pointing to your own computer.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem, could you elaborate a little more how did you do that?

Comment: Hi, I make my answer clearer and detailed. Happy to help you :)